# Is there any Documenation about the RANGE plugin?(other then the obvious)

Tags: ros, gazebo-all-versions, gazebo-9

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

i'm currently using this plugin: libgazebo_ros_range.so . I have to use this one with predefined params from other robots.

This is the part im using, it works all fine but I'm wondering if there is potential for improvement:

```
  <plugin filename="libgazebo_ros_range.so" name="gazebo_ros_range">
        <gaussianNoise>0.005</gaussianNoise>
        <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
        <updateRate>5</updateRate>
        <topicName>range/fl</topicName>
        <frameName>range_front_left_frame</frameName>
        <fov>0.1</fov>
        <radiation>ultrasound</radiation>   
   </plugin>
```

I cant find an proper explanation for all the parameters for example: can i change ultrasound to something else?

Do you guys have an link where i can read more about this plugin?
I looked through the [tutorial](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_gzplugins) and couldn't find anything. Also [this](http://gazebosim.org/api/) page couldn't help much, perhaps i'm using the page wrong?

Best Regards,
David

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/25055/is-there-any-documenation-about-the-range-plugin?(other-then-the-obvious)/) by [DavidSch](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/26127/davidsch/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-05-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You can find the code for [gazebo_ros_range.cpp](https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/blob/kinetic-devel/gazebo_plugins/src/gazebo_ros_range.cpp) on github.

More specifically, there is no alwaysOn parameter (you can remove it), and the fov and radiation parameters are only used to initialize the output ros messages (so they don't affect the plugin itself).

---

Originally posted by [nlamprian](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/8391/nlamprian/) with karma: 833 on 2020-05-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1